# Zoom out webview beyond webview size

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview which has zoom and loads a page size which goes beyond beyond webview,, I'm able to zoom out only when zoom in is pressed and it larger than screeen size, Requirement is to zoom(-) in and see the whole  page in webview.

This is current webview setting

```
final WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    ws.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    ws.setSupportZoom(true);
    ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: you need to make your web Page responsive using bootstrap.

Comment: you can also try `ws.zoomOut();`